# VirtualBox doesn't run x64 VMs with Vagrant on Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, 64-bit, virtualization, vagrant

When I execute `vagrant up` the process end with `Connection Timeout...` messages.

Trying to solve my problem I added `Ubuntu_64` to config file and enabled GUI, but no results.

The VMs which were successfully run with Vagrant are the Debian Wheezy 7.5 x32 built with puphpet and precise32. As we can see, only x32 VMs could be run on my machine. I don't know why.

Here is my machine info:

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04 x64
- Processor: AMD A8-4500M, 2 cores
- Virtualization is enabled in BIOS.

[image: screenshot]

- The latest Vagrant, VirtualBox and VirtualBox Extensions pack are installed
- my user is added to virtualbox group

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04x64 / VirtualBox 4.1.12 / Vagrant 1.6.3  and [puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64](https://vagrantcloud.com/puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64) works fine for me.

If you use old puphpet configuration file [generate](https://puphpet.com/) a new one and try again.

Answer (score 1):

The reason was in the BIOS: for Lenovo Edge E545 there is an **inversion** for the Virtualization Technology setting value: "Enabled" means "Disabled", and "Disabled" means "Enabled".